# Azure function with .net core 3.1 not triggering from Queue storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to trigger an Azure function when a new queue message is added. Both the storage account and the azure function are in the same region.

For my Azure Function, I clicked on Add, Azure Queue Storage Trigger, I gave my function a name, and the Queue name is the same name as my queue. I tried adding a new queue message, nothing is triggered.

I then tried modifying the code as the following:

```
using System;

[FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
[StorageAccount("storagetestaccount1")]

public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("queue1")] string myQueueItem, 
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

But still no success. Any idea what might be causing this?

This is my first azure function so not sure what's correct and what's not.

Comment: Use this:`[QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")]` then everything should be ok. And are you developing locally or on azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct code is this:

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("queueName", Connection = "connectString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

**Note**

If you develop locally, you should config your azure storage connect string in `local.settings.json`

[image]

If you develop in azure portal, you need to config connect string in `Application settings`:

[image]